# Is it possible to change the label of a button in Angular depending on a condition?

Tags: angular, button, label, angular-directive

I have the following button that I use throughout the different steps of a form.

```
<div class="col-2">
 <button class="main-buttton" (click)="increment()" label='Next' type='button' *ngIf="isShownNextButton"> 
 </button>
</div>
```

At the penultimate step I would like to modify the value of the label directive of the button so that it shows other text depending on a boolean I control in the ts.

Is this possible so that I don't have to implement another button and show it one or the other depending on the step I'm in?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is that what you need ? `[label]="booleanValue ? 'text_if_yes' : 'text_if_false'"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like that:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-2">
 <button class="main-buttton" (click)="increment()"  type='button'> 
   {{isShownNextButton ? 'Text if true' : 'Text if false`enter code here`'}}
 </button>
</div>
```

**component.ts**
in your component you can use a field. For example:

```
@Component()
export class SomeComponent{
  isShownNextButton: boolean= false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does anything speak against having the label condition logic in the typescript controller and just use a variable in html ?
`<button [label]='labelVariable' ...> </button>`